Aligning summarytools tables in Rmarkdown
How do you move summarytools tables in Rmarkdown?  For example, how do you move the following table to the left for PDFs?
title: "Moving summarytools tables"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document

library(summarytools)

summarytools::freq(cars$speed,headings=FALSE,report.nas = FALSE,cumul=FALSE)


Small workaround. Convert the summarytools to data.frame and then to flextable
First adjust knitr options and load necessary packages
```{r, setup}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(ft.align = "right")

if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")

p_load(summarytools, flextable)

``` 

Then you can do the table
```{r}

flextable(as.data.frame(summarytools::freq(cars$speed,headings=FALSE,report.nas = FALSE,cumul=FALSE)))

```


Thanks, that works!  If anyone else has other possible methods, feel free to post below.
